# Trying to add custom svg to angular material icon registry

Tags: angular, angular-material

As the title says, I am trying to add some custom svgs that I downloaded from https://simpleicons.org/
I have put my icons in a folder called **icons** in the **assets** directory in my application.
I have then injected the **MatIconRegistry** and **DomSanitizer** and added the svg like this:

```
constructor(
  private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,
  private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer
) {
  this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
    'facebook',
    this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      '/assets/icons/facebook.svg'
    )
  );
  this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
    'google',
    this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      '/assets/icons/google.svg'
    )
  );
  this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
    'twitter',
    this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(
      '/assets/icons/twitter.svg'
    )
  );
}
```

I have done this in the **AppComponent**.
In another component I am trying to use these icons. I have done this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn-block" type="button" color="secondary" mat-flat-button>
        <mat-icon>twitter</mat-icon> Continue with
        facebook
    </button>
</div>

<div>
    <button class="btn-block" type="button" color="secondary" mat-flat-button>
        <mat-icon>twitter</mat-icon> Continue with
        google
    </button>
</div>
```

But no icons are being shown.
I figured adding to the **AppComponent** would allow the icons to be used anywhere. Is this a bad assumption?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need a slightly different way of referencing the icon:

```
<mat-icon svgIcon="twitter"></mat-icon>
```

Comment: Ah, that was in the tutorial I was reading, but I assumed it was for an older version of angular material! Silly me; I will mark as the answer when it lets me

Comment: any idea how to sort out the alignment? It has no padding, margin or anything but it doesn't seem to align centrally :o

Comment: @r3plica If it is slightly below the middle, you can add some padding to the icon (bottom, to be specific, like 2px). This seems to be a problem with matIcon in general, at least from what I've encountered. (vertical-align: middle wasn't doing it for me.)

Comment: I fixed it by adding a class rule that set verticle-align to top which works